# Difficulty installing RSpec on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows-7, rubygems, rspec

I'm trying to get started with RSpec. I already had Ruby 1.8.7 installed on my Windows 7 machine.

So I typed `gem install rspec` and that seemed to work. But if I type `spec` in the command line, the command is not found. My path currently includes the `bin` folder in my `RUBY_HOME`.

If I look into the `C:\Users\Eric\.gem\specs\rubygems.org%80\quick\Marshal.4.8` directory, I do see four RSpec files such as `rspec-core-2.5.0.gemspec`. Nevertheless, the `spec` command fails even in this directory.

What needs to be done to install RSpec correctly? It would seem like a path issue, but I have been unable to find a directory where the `spec` command works, so I can't figure what to add to my path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `spec` command in RSpec 2. Try `rake spec` or `rspec spec`.

Comment: That's what I get for using a 3 year old tutorial.

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and use `bundle exec rspec spec`, is this recommended as well? I forget the logic behind it, but it's now a practice in my daily duties.

Comment: @Tass, that's the correct way to do this if you're using Bundler.

Comment: Just noticed @lordtyron's response, too. Doh?

Comment: What if i am outside rails project and try to run the sample tests on a folder? Then `bundle exec rpsec spec` seems not to work as i dont have a Gem file over there. Then how can I invoke the `rspec spec` command?

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, try this `bundle exec rspec spec`